# Is it possible to specify compression level when calling str.encode('zlib') in Python?

Tags: python, encoding, compression, zlib

Is it possible to specify compression level when calling str.encode('zlib') in Python?

```
'hi world'.encode('zlib')  # compress the string
```

Comment: Are your strings all short like that?

Comment: Are you aware of the [`zlib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html) module, and just wondering if there is a way to specify the level without using it?

Comment: @Cameron no, the strings are not short. Just showing an example.

Comment: @dano in the str.encode docs (https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html) it is said that `Changed in version 2.7: Support for keyword arguments added.` so I thought it is possible to specify some parameters to the encoder.

Comment: @yuku that just refers to being able to do this: `'hi world'.encode(encoding='zlib')`. In Python 2.6, trying that returns `TypeError: encode() takes no keyword arguments`, but it works fine in 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you could just directly call [zlib.compress()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html#zlib.compress)
The [docs for the zlib encoding](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings) show that under the covers that's all it's doing